# Subspaces of finite fields viewed as vector spaces on itself

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

How can I find the number of linear subspaces of dimensions 1 and 2 of the n-
dimensional vector space $\mathbb{Z}^n_p$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Do you mean the $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{Z}^n_p$ or the $3$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{Z}^3_p$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Sorry I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1-dimensional subspaces, just count all possible non-zero vectors, and then figure out how much you are over counting (ie. $x$ and $y$ will generate the same subspace iff $x=\lambda y$ for some $0\neq \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

For 2-dimensional subspaces, consider how you can choose $2$ linearly independent vectors from $\mathbb{Z}_p^3$. There are $p^3-1$ choices for the first vector (everything except zero), and $p^3-p$ choices for the second vector (everything except a multiple of the first).

Now, two pairs $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ generate the same subspace iff there is an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix maps one to the other. How many invertible $2\times 2$ matrices are there? Again, $(p^2-1)$ choices for the first vector, and $(p^2-p)$ choices for the second vector. Hence you get
$$
\frac{(p^3-1)(p^3-p)}{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}
$$
possibilities for 2-dimensional subspaces.

More generally, just google "Gaussian binomial coefficient", or read [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2193)

Comment: Could you please be more specific for the 2-dimensional case? How would invertible matrices work?

Comment: I have edited the answer with some details.